# Oauth library for iOS (in particular Yelp)

Tags: oauth

I want to add Yelp search into my application.

To do this I need to use Yelps Oauth authentication. This sounded easy as I've made some server applications before.

However, I keep getting an `INVALID_SIGNATURE` with the code I have created to make and retrieve data from a constructed URL.

I have checked the signature output by my app and it is exactly the same as the one they provide at http://api.yelp.com (I've even checked the two strings (before the hashing) at http://www.textdiff.com and they said they were the same)

It seems I hit a dead end and cannot get around this error.

*Can anyone point me in the right direction with why my signature might not work*

and/or

*Can someone point me to a good iOS Oauth tutorial and library (any library I have found has poor documentation on how to use it)*

Thanks

Comment: I maintain a somewhat modified copy of the MPOAuth library [here](https://github.com/H2CO3/MPOAuthiOS), I've documented it so you can use it as a drag-and-drop project.

Comment: I cannot import `<MPOAuth/MPOAuth.h>`, how do I add this to the frameworks?

Comment: Just copy-paste the files.

Comment: Tried that, however, at least one of the headers also references `<MPOAuth/...>`

Comment: Also, the library seems broken for the newest iOS, as there are many errors/warnings such as wrongly linked files and is not suitable for ARC

Comment: Then turn off ARC for its files. None of my projects currently support ARC.